# How can I find the following convolution sum?

Tags: convolution, discrete-time

$$ h[n]= \left( \frac{8}{9} \right) ^n u[n-3] $$

And the function is:
$$x[n] =
           \begin{cases}
                      2 &         \text{if } 0 \leq n \leq9, \\                               
                      0 &         \text{ else}.
           \end{cases}$$

In order to find the convolution sum $y[n]=x[n]*h[n]$:

$$y[n]=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x[n]\cdot h[k-n]}$$

$$y[n]=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} {x[n]\cdot \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n\cdot u[k-3-n]}$$

How do I proceed from here?

In essence, how do I evaluate a finite sum for these conditions?

Comment: Hint: $x[n]=0 \ \text{for} \ k<0 \ \text{and} \  k>9$

Comment: Yes, but what about $h[n]$? Is it $0$ for $n>k-3$